# Multiple MVC controllers in .NET Core with different levels of security

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

In my ASP.NET Core MVC app I have two controllers, both mapped with route-attributes. One should only be accessible after authentication and the other is public.

This is how I add authentication and mvc to the pipeline:

```
  app.UseMiddleware<AuthMiddleware>();
  app.UseMvc();
```

The problem is that both will require authentication and the public one will not work. If I replace the order of the above two lines the public one will work but not the other one. Can I separate this somehow so that the public one is still mapped with its route-attributes and executed before authentication and the other one after authentication?

(The AuthMiddleware basically checks for specific header values and adds a security principal to the request thread so that any following code that requires authentication is working.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not a 100% sure if I understand you correctly, but you can use [conditional middleware](https://www.devtrends.co.uk/blog/conditional-middleware-based-on-request-in-asp.net-core) to achieve middleware usage/mapping only under certain conditions.

Comment: Thanks. I just added a pass-through in my AuthMiddleware based on the request path.